# Is there a way to catch the Search key so that the Google Voice Search dialog doesn't appear?

Tags: android, keypress

I'm aware that the home key cannot be caught, and I'm worried that a long-press on the Search key is another "Android-OS protected" key press.  Just for testing, I tried to catch all keys with this code within my Activity, but it does not stop the Google Voice Search dialog from being triggered.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
{
    return true;
}
```

**Edit: I tested this code on the Nexus One, and it successfully blocks the key event on that phone, but I still have this problem on the Droid 2.  Both are running Froyo 2.2**

Answer (score 0):

Im not at my pc, so im just gonna paste a search result.

I think you'r looking for this:

Activity | Android Developers
boolean, onSearchRequested(). This hook is called when the user signals the   desire to start a search.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html